# Black screen on PC boot

Tags: windows-7, boot, desktop-computer

From time to time i will get a following black screen when booting a PC:
[image: black screen]
Resetting PC helps and it boots correctly. Can anyone tell me what could be a reason?

Comment: More information would help. For example, if the PC is more than four or five years old, it might be the clock/CMOS battery is dead... but there could be other causes. Model? Any extra cards? What processes show in Startup in SysInternals' Autoruns?

Comment: The PC is 8 years old.
It happens before the windows start (windows 7 in this case - which was installed after formatting recently) so it doesn't matter.
Pc is not a prebuilt - it was built manually from parts back then.
https://scontent-waw1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t34.0-12/24726634_1489121264469718_1772888525_n.png?oh=fba14e3cf237757d6107c868b68fbebe&oe=5A28B12E
here is the list of parts

Comment: 8 years? First thing I'd check would be the clock/CMOS cell.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik by checking do you mean replacing it?

Comment: If you have a battery tester (e.g. voltmeter with resistive load), use it. If not, replace it... most coin cells are less than $US0.50.